# Misma versión de gcc distintos mensajes en la compilación

Tags: c++, gcc

Es pura curiosidad más que problema.

Estoy compilando el mismo código **C++** en un pc con [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) Stretch y en una [raspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) con [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/) Stretch. Ambas traen por defecto [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) **version 6.3.0 20170516**.

Pues el tema es que obtengo distintos mensajes en la compilación, que aunque no afectan al resultado final pues compila todo sin errores, pero tanta nota sólo en raspbian me llaman bastante a atención.

¿Alguna pista al respecto? Pego un cacho de los mensajes de salida, por que encima es bastante.

Salida en la raspberry:

```
In file included from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Configuracion.hpp:7:0,                                                                                                                                             
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Gateway.hpp:4,                                                                                                                                                     
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Gateway.cpp:1:                                                                                                                                                     
/home/pi/.hunter/_Base/60e121f/2620915/15e92a9/Install/include/nlohmann/json.hpp: In member function ‘nlohmann::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType,
 NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer>::value_type& nlohmann::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSer
ializer>::operator[](nlohmann::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer>::size_type) [with ObjectType = s
td::map; ArrayType = std::vector; StringType = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; BooleanType = bool; NumberIntegerType = long long int; NumberUnsignedType = long long unsigned int; NumberFloatType = double; Al
locatorType = std::allocator; JSONSerializer = nlohmann::adl_serializer]’:                                                                                                                                       
/home/pi/.hunter/_Base/60e121f/2620915/15e92a9/Install/include/nlohmann/json.hpp:15378:17: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘std::vector<nlohmann::basic_json<>, std::allocator<nlohmann::basic_json<
> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const nlohmann::basic_json<>*, std::vector<nlohmann::basic_json<>, std::allocator<nlohmann::basic_json<> > > >}’ will change in GCC 7.1                  
                 m_value.array->insert(m_value.array->end(),                                                                                                                                                     
                 ^~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                         
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,                                                                                                                                                               
                 from /home/pi/.hunter/_Base/60e121f/2620915/15e92a9/Install/include/nlohmann/json.hpp:54,                                                                                                       
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Configuracion.hpp:7,                                                                                                                                               
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Gateway.hpp:4,                                                                                                                                                     
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Gateway.cpp:1:                                                                                                                                                     
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h: In member function ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [
with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = nlohmann::basic_json<>; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nl
ohmann::basic_json<> > >]’:                                                                                                                                                                                      
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:502:4: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::basic_json<> >
, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::basic_json<> > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nl
ohmann::basic_json<> > > >::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::basic_json<> > >}’ will change in GCC 7.1                               
    __i = _M_t._M_emplace_hint_unique(__i, std::piecewise_construct,                                                                                                                                             
    ^~~                                                                                                                                                                                                          
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/vector:64:0,                                                                                                                                                            
                 from /home/pi/.hunter/_Base/60e121f/2620915/15e92a9/Install/include/nlohmann/json.hpp:57,                                                                                                       
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Configuracion.hpp:7,                                                                                                                                               
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Gateway.hpp:4,                                                                                                                                                     
                 from /home/pi/lab/cnenos/src/Gateway.cpp:1:                                                                                                                                                     
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h: In member function ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, cons
t value_type&) [with _Tp = nlohmann::basic_json<>; _Alloc = std::allocator<nlohmann::basic_json<> >]’:                                                                                                           
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:1052:7: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘std::vector<nlohmann::basic_json<>, std::allocator<nlohmann::basic_json<> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal
_iterator<const nlohmann::basic_json<>*, std::vector<nlohmann::basic_json<>, std::allocator<nlohmann::basic_json<> > > >}’ will change in GCC 7.1                                                                
       insert(const_iterator __position, size_type __n, const value_type& __x)
```

Repetido varias por cada archivo :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Alguna pista al respecto?

El estándar de C++ no especifica cómo debe estar implementada la librería estándar. Simplemente dice qué funcionalidad debe proporcionar.

Esto permite beneficiarse de la implementación más óptima para diferentes tipos de hardware.

En tu caso, un PC suele montar, típicamente, un procesador Intel o un AMD, que se basan en una arquitectura [CISC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing), mientras que raspberry usa ARM, cuya arquitectura es [RISC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing).

Esto tiene sus implicaciones a la hora de realizar las diferentes operaciones. Así, es altamente probable que la implementación de la librería estándar sea diferente y que ello genere diferentes mensajes de warning o error ante una misma situación.